# ASP.Net Core & EF Core : recursively include childs and map to view model

Tags: entity-framework-core, mapping

I've got somes classes that represent a hierarchical organization. To simplify there is one **Entreprise** class (Enterprise) that contains some properties and a collection of **Unite** (Organization item).

The second **Unite** class have some properties and potentially a collection of **Unite** as the enterprise has.

The number of level (unites with child and childs and childs, etc...) isn't known.

Finally i've got a ViewModel Class to expose a partial view of this datas.

### Model && ViewModel

```
[Table("Entreprise", Schema = "Structure")]
public partial class Entreprise
{

    public Entreprise()
    {
        Unites = new HashSet<Structure.Unite>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Libelle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Structure.Unite> Unites { get; set; }

}

[Table("Unite", Schema = "Structure")]
public partial class Unite
{

    #region Constructeur

    public Unite()
    {
        UnitesChild = new HashSet<Structure.Unite>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Entreprise")]
    public int? IdEntreprise { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UniteParent")]
    public int? IdUniteParent { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Libelle { get; set; }

    public virtual Structure.Entreprise Entreprise { get; set; }

    public virtual Structure.Unite UniteParent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Structure.Unite> UnitesChild { get; set; }

}


public class ListWithUnites
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Libelle { get; set; }
    public List<UniteCL> Unites { get; set; }

    public class UniteCL
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Libelle { get; set; }
        public List<UniteCL> Unites { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What i want to do is to :

1 - Load Enterprise --> childs unites and also load Unite --> childs unites until the last level

2 - Map the result of the query to the view model

So many thanks in advance if you've got an advice for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've found a pretty good answer :

1. As i want to get a json object from my api, i don't need explictely a viewmodel
2. As the entities of type Unite are linked to Entreprise AND themselves, i can tell EFCore to include only *Entreprise.UnitesChild* in my query and it will do the magic and set cascaded relations between Unites.
3. I can use a recursive function into my select

So this is the final code :

```
            public ActionResult<object> ListWithUnites()
    {
        return _dbContext.Structure_Entreprises
            .Include(ent => ent.Unites) 
            .ToList() 
            .Select(ent => new 
            {
                ent.Id,
                ent.Libelle,
                Unites = ent.Unites
                    .Where(w => w.IdUniteHierarchique == null)
                    .Select(uni => ListWithUnites_LoadUnites(uni)).ToList() // load unites recursively
            }).ToList();
    }

    private object ListWithUnites_LoadUnites(Unite unite)
    {
        return new
        {
            unite.Id,
            unite.Libelle,
            Unites = unite.UnitesHierarchiques.Select(uniChild => ListWithUnites_LoadUnites(uniChild)).ToList()
        };
    }
```